# aws ecs: creating access credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-security-group

I have created a flask app using Fargate ecs.

On this setup, I have a security group attached to the load balancer where I can adjust the inbound rules with the IPs that I want to have access to this app. That works ok.

However, what I want is to attach authentication credentials to the Fargate in order to give access to the ones having these tokens instead of using IP rules that I am doing now.

Is there a way to do it in aws or do I need to do it internally in the flask app?

thanks

Comment: Its not clear what you would like to do? Assign some tokens to a SG of your ALB?

Comment: @Marcin exactly. add some tokens to the SG of my ALB. Searching on the aws console i cant find a way. I can only edit inbound,outbound,tags in a security group.

Comment: You can't add any tokens to SGs. Its all about IP ranges, internet gateways etc. No custom elements there unfortunately.